# Is there an elegant solution to empty variables affecting implode output?

Tags: php, arrays, symfony-1.4

Here's my code:

```
$a = $request->getParameter('a');
$b = $request->getParameter('b');
$c = $request->getParameter('c');

$d = array($a, $b, $c);

$e = implode(", ", $d);
```

Unfortunately, if either a, b, or c is empty (these are from HTML checkboxes), it's formatted improperly. For example, if b was unchecked it would look like this:

```
a, , c
```

I want it to look like this:

```
a, c
```

I understand that I could check if each one was empty and if so, remove that one from the array line, but it seems like it would be quite messy. Is there a more elegant way to fix it?

Comment: How about not adding the empty parameters to the array in the first place?

Comment: Just replace `(space),` with empty value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$e = implode(", ", array_filter($d));
```